# Text input fields sometimes not responding because of labels

Tags: javascript, html, materialize

I'm making a website using materializecss framework and encouraged a bug where sometimes inputs are not responding correctly.

This sometimes happens when clicking for example on first input, and that targeting higher part of the second input. What happens it that first input is still being clicked.

It seems that

```
 <label>name1</label>
```

Are causing it. Is there any way to solve this problem?

Here is the [example](https://jsfiddle.net/eoadr7m5/).

Comment: Use different ids: https://jsfiddle.net/eoadr7m5/1/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You used the same ID (`input_text`) for every input, an ID is unique, try using a different ID for every input and link each label's `for` attribute to the good ID.

[**Here's your fixed JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/8p87m5Ls/)

Answer (score 1):

You had input fields with same id.

```
<input id="input_text" type="text"  name="bName1" class="validate">
<input id="input_value" type="text" name="bName2" class="validate">
<input id="input_string" type="text" name="bName3" class="validate">
```

***ID***: The most important aspect of the id attribute is that it must be absolutely unique. Unlike the class attribute, which may apply the same value to many elements in a page, an id that’s applied to an element must not match an id used anywhere else on the same page.

Fixed your [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/JavaUIDeveloper/eoadr7m5/3/)